# svcutil fails to generate code from wsdl file

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, soap

A company I am working for are developing their own in house solution and need to enable their clients to continue using SOAP services for various versions.

When using `svcutil /sc *.wsdl *.xsd` I get error;

```
svcutil /sc *.wsdl *.xsd
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.8.3928.0]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Error: All parts of message in operation  must either contain type or element.


Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Referenced type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' is only valid for encoded SOAP.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.uk/myapp/']/wsdl:portType[@name='ProposalPortType']


Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.uk/myapp/']/wsdl:portType[@name='ProposalPortType']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.uk/myapp/']/wsdl:binding[@name='ProposalBinding']


Error: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.uk/myapp/']/wsdl:binding[@name='ProposalBinding']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.uk/myapp/']/wsdl:service[@name='Proposal-service']/wsdl:port[@name='ProposalPort']


Generating files...
Warning: No code was generated.
```

If I remove this from message

```
<part name="attachment" type="oneapp:ArrayOfBinary"/>
```

full message

```
<message name="ProposalOutput">
    <!-- This is the main message content which describes the Proposal -->
    <part name="out" element="xsd1:Proposal"/>
    <!-- There may be zero to many attachment parts -->
    <!--<part name="attachment" type="oneapp:ArrayOfBinary"/>-->
</message>`
```

Code is then generated, however with the explicit removal of these items I am not entirely sure what I have removed or what effect it will have on a new service that will need to be created.

My question is, why would these two items have caused code generation to fail and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Is your WSDL document about Java WebService?If so, the svcutil command used should look like this:

```
     svcutil *.wsdl *.xsd /language:C#
```

According to the information you provided, I found that you did not add language, which may cause this problem.

For more information about svcutil,please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe

Comment: Sorry, I didnt see this response until now.  I suspect that the this was created in Java, however we need to replicate it .net now

Comment: this didnt work as got this response `svcutil *.wsdl *.xsd /language:Java
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.8.3928.0]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Error: The value 'Java' passed to the /language argument does not represent a defined language and it could not be loaded as a fully qualified CLR type.

If you would like more help, type "svcutil /?"`

Comment: You can try changing the language to C#.

Comment: you can try to add a service reference to VS to generate a proxy class directly, or use WSDL.exe.

Comment: tried via VS, but ive not tried WSDL.exe, ill try that